# Check if specific string in table-seperated values (tsv) exists with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a tsv as variable (IDS) which contains many Ids.

Example:

```
3aa6da2b
6adc1837
c6c79e2b
06ca5611
68f00b8b
ed4079ec
9d842eae
```

I want to check if for example 06ca5611 exists in the tsv.
I can not find a good way for this problem.
I tried `echo "$IDS" | grep -q "$ID"` but nothing was found.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `-q` here?
This works

```
[ /]$ IDS="3aa6da2b
6adc1837
c6c79e2b
06ca5611
68f00b8b
ed4079ec
9d842eae"
[ /]$ ID=06ca5611
[ /]$ echo "$IDS" | grep "$ID"
06ca5611
```